# Free DB to import on SQL Developer

Tags: sql, oracle11g, oracle-sqldeveloper

I haven't used SQLDeveloper for a while and I was wondering if it'd be possible to download free data (with tables connected and so on) that I can import to SQLDeveloper to play around with.

Comment: Oracle Database Express Editions

Comment: Not sure I follow.  SQL Developer is a SQL (and PL/SQL) IDE.  It is not a database.  It has no tables.  It has no databases.  You can't import data into an IDE.  If you download and install the Oracle Database Express Edition you could install the sample schemas that Oracle provides and then use SQL Developer to query the data in those tables.

Comment: That's the piece of info I needed, thanks Justin.